# why the TURTLEBOT localization is so good?

Tags: turtlebot, xtion, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i have a turtlebot 2 with asus axtion pro and everything is working good with the navigation , but i have a question about the  localization , i have tried to turn the  camera by some angles to the left  form it's initial position  so that it's not aligned with robot and i'm suprised that the localization is still giving a good position , how is that ? i thought that amcl depend on the laser scan ? so how do the turtlebot to localize it self despite a bad alignement of the camera ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299868/why-the-turtlebot--localization-is-so-good-?/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if I understand your question.
Did you misalign the camera in purpose and then checked on rviz only to see that the lidar is still aligned with the map?
If so it means your robot is delocalized, amcl is forcing the robot to have a position derivated from the transform between camera and robot. So if your transform is wrong (after moving the camera) your robot's position will have a rotational error equal to the amount by which you rotated your camera.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0